# call inner function from tkinter Button

Tags: python, tkinter, scope

i have an button

```
b3 = Button(master, text="Answer", width=14, height=3, command=lambda: sendMessage())
```

and worker() function which has inner function sendMessage(). i put sendMessage() in worker() cauz there is a few defined local variables which i should have in sendMessage(). but now i cant call sendMessage() from this Button, i have an error - **NameError: global name 'sendMessage' is not defined**

how can i tie inner function with Button ?

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You cannot, you can only call functions that are in your current namespace and since `sendMessage()` is inside `worker()` it is present only in the local namespace of `worker()`. The only way to achieve this is to instantiate the button inside `worker()` and the correct syntax is `b3 = Button(..., command=sendMessage)`